# is there a way that works , to change spaces in a string to underscore?

Tags: macos, lua, terminal

```
function exists(f)
    filetry=""
    local fileBuffer={}

    for w in x:gmatch("%S+") do 
        table.insert(fileBuffer,w)
    end

    for i, v in ipairs(fileBuffer) do 
        filetry=filetry.."_"..v
    end

    f=filetry

    if os.execute("test -e "..f) == true then
        return true 
    else 
        return false
    end
end
```

i need to change space characters to underscore
so i can find the file in termanal
i have tried to use apis but it's not working for me due to my computer deletes it after install it. so i just need a function that can make spaces , underscore and ,use the termanal test command to find a file

Comment: I recommend replacing things like `"test -e "..f` with `("test -e %s"):format(f)` to make it easier to read when the string eventually gets longer and ends up having 8 concatenations in one line of code. It should also be a bit faster, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I also recommend changing `if variable == true then return true else return false end` constructs with a simple `return variable`, or if it's a function that returns more than one argument, saving it in a variable first, and doing `local result = os.execute(...); return result;`. This keeps the code less cluttered and easier to read.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = str:gsub("%s+", "_")
-- where `str` is the string you want to remove the spaces from.
-- Replaces multiple consecutive space characters with single _.
-- Remove the `+` to make it replace each space character with its own _.
```

Example:

```
print( ("Hello world"):gsub("%s+", "_") )
-- will print "Hello_world"
```

EDIT: Note that string.gsub() creates a new string instead of modifying the old one, which is why in my first example the reasignation `str = str:gsub...` was necessary.